# Finding the position of the global optimum with Pytorch

Tags: neural-networks, python

I have a dataset with 22 parameters and I did a PolynomialFeatures = 2 to find the influence of interaction. This was then fitted to an Artificial Neural Network with the lowest loss being around 0.02.

Now I want to find the position of the global optimum, which is the negative of the global minimum. How do I find the position of the global optimum with PyTorch?

Answer (score 4):

The description of the particular network is not specific enough to understand what the model is, or how it works. Additionally, the terminology seems confused because datasets don't have *parameters*, they have features.

However, the specifics of the network is not material to answering the question. In general, NNs don't have unique global optima because the loss function is non-convex (from the perspective of the network parameters). Some elaboration:

- [Can we use MLE to estimate Neural Network weights?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145902/can-we-use-mle-to-estimate-neural-network-weights/145907#145907)
- [Why can't we just add a penalty to make the Neural Network objective convex?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569801/why-cant-we-just-add-a-penalty-to-make-the-neural-network-objective-convex/569806#569806)

Finding a global optimum of a high-dimensional, non-convex function such as a neural network is typically intractable due to the very large size of the parameter space. Global optimization is hard in a small number of dimensions, and becomes much harder as the number of dimensions increases. Even the search space is "small," global optimization is a challenging task. See:

- [Optimization when Cost Function Slow to Evaluate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310)
- [Why does Bayesian Optimization perform poorly in more than 20 Dimensions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564528/why-does-bayesian-optimization-perform-poorly-in-more-than-20-dimensions)

Moreover, local optima are often very high quality for neural networks. See:

- [Understanding "almost all local minimum have very similar function value to the global optimum"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203288/understanding-almost-all-local-minimum-have-very-similar-function-value-to-the/203300#203300)

These facts are common to neural networks in general, and not specific to PyTorch or any other neural network software.